# Laravel decrypt issue

Tags: laravel, encryption, laravel-5

I have a problem with decrypting some values that I have just recently tried encrypting. I've generated the key [as stated in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/encryption).

And I've imported my values with my controller as the following:

```
public function importEquipment (Request $request)
                                                                {
    if($request->file('imported-file'))
      {
                $path = $request->file('imported-file')->getRealPath();
                $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
                    })->get();
                    if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){
                        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                            Equipment::create([
                              'active' => $value->active,
                              'licensePlate' => encrypt($value->licensePlate),
                              'notes' => $value->notes,
                              'purchaseDate' => $value->purchaseDate,
                              'titleNumber' => encrypt($value->titleNumber),
                              'tires' => $value->tires,
                              'unit_type' => $value->unit_type,
                              'unitTypeLabel' => $value->unitTypeLabel,
                              'unit_id' => $value->unit_id,
                              'VIN' => encrypt($value->VIN),
                              'year' => $value->year,
                              'customerID' => 1,
                            ]);
                        }
                    }
                }
        Session::flash('flash_message','Equipment successfully imported!');
        return back();
    }
```

As you can see there are three values that I chose to encrypt, and it looks like they are successfully generated in their longtext fields.

However, when I go to access the "index" of equipment through my site, I get something like this `eyJpdiI6Im5IUnFkdEFNS3JDV1RQajdyQVZMMEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiYWZGYXU0Y1dTcG5aOEFWbHI0amR6QT09IiwibWFjIjoiNzkwNWQ1YzYwOGJjZjdmMTc1Zjg0ZTVmNWZkMjViY2M5YjA5OTM4MGJhYjE1YjNkYTQ5ZjI0MDg2M2YxM2EyZiJ9` when I print the following `{{$equipment->VIN}}`, but when I do `{{decrypt($equipment->VIN}}`, nothing appears.

Am I doing something wrong with the decryption and is there an appropriate way for this with decrypting in a `@foreach` environment?

Comment: Since you're just encrypting a string, use `Crypt::encryptString($value->VIN)` and later use `Crypt::decryptString($equipment->VIN)`. While this may not 100% solve your problem, it will same you a bit of overhead.

Comment: How would I go about decrypting the value to display in the blade under a foreach? Would it just be {{Crypt::decryptString($equipment->VIN)}}? Thank you for the suggestion, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: since you're using the `Crypt` Facade, you would need `\Crypt` with a backslash prepended

Comment: So I gave it a try using {{\Crypt::decryptString($equipment->VIN)}} in the blade and 'VIN' => Crypt::encryptString($value->VIN) in the importer but while there are values in the database (again look to be encrypted), nothing pops up on the blade... any ideas on what to try next to locate the issue?

Comment: can you check what is the value of `$value->VIN` when you import the excel?

Comment: What's the result of `dd(decrypt($equipment->VIN));`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir - where would you like me to pull that, from another controller or from the import (just in case it makes a difference).

Comment: Please try both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will helps you...

try

```
 Crypt::decrypt($equipment->VIN));
```

or

```
 Crypt::decrypt($value->VIN));
```

for more information Visit  [Decrypting A Value](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security)

Comment: So in an index format surrounded by @foreach, I would use it in a blade as {{\Crypt::decrypt($equipment->VIN)}}?

Comment: ok ... try that code by using {{Crypt::decrypt($equipment->VIN))}} and i think it will work for you...

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like it was working already, my problem was that my importer wasn't actually pulling the data in. Thank you for your answer though - I appreciate the help!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)